# Redux-Form matchDispatchToProps not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

when I try to pass my actions into the reduxForm call it doesn't map my actions to the props. I get this error:

[image: Error Imaged]
I've included the steps for error recreation below. Many thanks for your help!

**My Test Action Creator with redux-thunk**

```
export function signUpUser({ firstName, lastName, email, password, passwordConfirm }) {
  console.log("action: ", firstName)
  console.log("action: ", lastName)
  console.log("action: ", email)
  console.log("action: ", password)
  console.log("action: ", passwordConfirm)
  return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({ 
      type: AUTH_USER, 
      payload: response.data.message 
    });
    }
}
```

**VSCode Method Signature Helper**

```
(alias) reduxForm(config: ReduxFormConfig, mapStateToProps?: MapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps?: MapDispatchToPropsFunction | MapDispatchToPropsObject): ClassDecorator
import reduxForm
```

**My call to reduxForm**

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
...
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'authentication'
}, null, signUpUser)(Login);
```

**My Usage of the action in my React.Component**

```
handleFormSubmit(values) {
    this.validateFields(values);

    console.log("works")
    if (this.state.errors.email.exists && this.state.errors.email.valid && this.state.errors.password.match) {
      console.log("works2")
      this.props.signUpUser(values);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried like this `export default reduxForm({
  form: 'authentication'
}, null, {signUpUser: signUpUser})(Login);` ?

Comment: Hey @JyothiBabuAraja, I am using v6 so Jaganathan's answer below works. I do get where you're coming from with the ES5 syntax though :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If @Jyothi's comment did not work for you, then you might be using `redux-form` v6. In the version 6, you have to use your own `redux-form` `connect`ion as shown below.

```
class MyForm extends Component {}
MyForm = reduxForm(config)(MyForm)
MyForm = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyForm)
export default MyForm
```

Here is an [example](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.14/examples/initializeFromState/) from `redux-form` doc.

Comment: Awesome! I am indeed using v6. I read the docs but it was a bit confusing, your explanation really helps. Thanks :)